# Calculate the total price of a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, database

While im not new to databases, i am out of practice and was wondering how to create a total price attribute for a store database.

The table has the attributes: PT KEy, Product ID, Quantity, offer, Total item price(the product table has the prices, this field is just the price multiplied by the quantity), offer.

I am trying to make a field that adds up all the Total item prices in the table, giving the entire price of the transaction.

Should i make this field in another table or do it in the current one? if so how?

Comment: Are you sure you want to store easily derived data?

Comment: You probably want to use [SUM()](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) but your question is too unclear to write an useful answer.

Comment: i have to be able to show each which store branches are the most successful on any given day, do you think that i should just use functions / queries to do so? I just thought storing them as an attribute may be easier.

Comment: *The table has the attributes* Show this as complete CREATE TABLE script, not as approximate description.

Comment: *I am trying to make a field that adds up all the Total item prices in the table, giving the entire price of the transaction.* WHERE do you want to create this column? in this table - for this value to be the same in all rows relative to the transaction? Strange need... obtain this value in a query when it needed really.

Comment: Well from what the others have said I have decided to leave it as a query instead of making it a field, and just re-arranged some other fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end i made it a calculated field in that was generated in a query. I removed any calculated fields of the such and replaced them in the queries.